# Global.asax and inheritance

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a parent app and a child app. Which currently have two separate Global.asax files. I'm trying to have this child app inherit from the parent app's Global.asax file.

So I have a file in my App_Code folder with all of the code in it as follows:

```
namespace NsGlobalAsax
{
    public class GlobalAsax : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        public GlobalAsax()
        {
            //
            // TODO: Add constructor logic here
            //
        }



        void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // add some data to the Session so permanent SessionId is assigned
            // otherwise new SessionId is assigned to the user until some data
            // is actually written to Session
            Session["Start"] = DateTime.Now;

            // get current context
            HttpContext currentContext = HttpContext.Current;

            if (currentContext != null)
            {
                if (!OnlineVisitorsUtility.Visitors.ContainsKey(currentContext.Session.SessionID))
                    OnlineVisitorsUtility.Visitors.Add(currentContext.Session.SessionID, new WebsiteVisitor(currentContext));
            }

        }

        void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Code that runs when a session ends. 
            // Note: The Session_End event is raised only when the sessionstate mode
            // is set to InProc in the Web.config file. If session mode is set to StateServer 
            // or SQLServer, the event is not raised.

            if (this.Session != null)
                OnlineVisitorsUtility.Visitors.Remove(this.Session.SessionID);
        }



        public void Application_AuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String cookieName = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName;
            HttpCookie authCookie = Context.Request.Cookies[cookieName];

            if (null == authCookie)
            {//There is no authentication cookie.
                return;
            }

            FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = null;

            try
            {
                authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Write the exception to the Event Log.
                return;
            }

            if (null == authTicket)
            {//Cookie failed to decrypt.
                return;
            }

            //When the ticket was created, the UserData property was assigned a
            //pipe-delimited string of group names.
            String[] groups = authTicket.UserData.Split(new char[] { '|' });

            //Create an Identity.
            GenericIdentity id = new GenericIdentity(authTicket.Name, "LdapAuthentication");

            //This principal flows throughout the request.
            GenericPrincipal principal = new GenericPrincipal(id, groups);

            Context.User = principal;

        }
    }

}
```

Now I have my parent Global.asax file as follows:

```
<%@ Application Language="C#" CodeBehind="Global.asax.cs" src="Global.asax.cs"  Inherits="RootAsax.BaseGlobal"    %>
```

and here is the codebehind file:

```
namespace RootAsax
{
    public class BaseGlobal : NsGlobalAsax.GlobalAsax
    {}
}
```

now here is my child app Global.asax file:

```
<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="FormsAuthAd.Global" Language="C#" %>
```

and here is the codebehind file:

```
namespace FormsAuthAd
{
    public class Global : NsGlobalAsax.GlobalAsax
    {
    }
}
```

Both classes in the codebehindfiles are inheriting from the source in the App_Code folder, however, the authentication status is not being passed from one app to another. For instance, if I login on the parent app, the authentication does not carry over to the child app. The opposite is also true.

I'm hoping I gave you guys enough detail.

Thanks!

EDIT:

Heinzi stated in the comments that this is not an inheritance issue. I need to figure out how to have the child app **use** the parent's Global.asax file. If i delete the child app's Global.asax file authentication does not work at all for the child app. Any ideas?

Comment: Why should inheritance from the same source lead to a shared authentication status? If both `B1` and `B2` inherit from `A`, this *only* means that `B1` and `B2` can be used wherever `A` is required. As a bonus, to save you some typing, `B1` and `B2` behave as if the code written in `A` had been copy-and-pasted into `B1` and `B2` (with some exceptions and differences, but that's the general idea). Inheritance has *nothing* to do with any kind of shared state (such as login credentials).

Comment: Yeah, you are right. How would I go about eliminating the child app's Global.asax file and have it use the parent's Global.asax then?

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with "whose Global.asax file is used", it's just an issue of sharing credentials between two apps. There are quite a few Google hits when searching for [aspx shared authentication](http://www.google.com/search?q=aspx+shared+authentication), but I don't know enough about that to recommend a particular solution. I'd suggest looking into that and, if you still need help, ask a new question here.

Comment: how do you create the cookie when a user logs in? could you write the code?

Comment: @Lilluda5 please provide your code

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem related to inheritance.

If you want to authenticate  users in different websites you should implement a  Single sign-on strategy http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on

There are many example and way to do it. It is quite complex.

Answer (score 0):

> i think every Application has its own Session and State.. it is not possible to pass
>   the Application object. one way it is done is by an Application
>   persisting the data in a database and the other application reading
>   the data from the common shared database and figuring out how to make
>   sense of it.